# How to pass a php variable to twig template

Tags: php, twig, templating

I have found quite a few discussions on this but I can't seem to make it work. I define the variable in php this way

`$theme_name = 'layout1';`

So I tried the following to get 'layout1' to show in my CMS template using {{ theme.name }} by each one of the following, one at a time, but none of them worked. The ones with $twig gave undefined variable 'twig'.

```
$theme['name'] = $theme_name;
$app["twig"]->addGlobal("name", $theme_name);
$GLOBALS['theme'] = 'layout1';
$twig->addGlobal('themename', 'layout1');
```

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: where is the call (code) of your template file ?

Comment: I have this in my cms template {{ theme.name }} but nothing shows where this code is.

Answer (score 3):

Simple as that:

```
$twig->addGlobal('themename', $variation);
```

and in you template file you just call

```
{{themename}}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to understand this command. Does it define a global twig variable called 'themename' with contents of a previous defined php variable called $variation? It's hard to find the defintion of this on sensiolabs site, although to coders it's probably obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The Twig documentation covers this.

> https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html
>
> https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#globals

A global variable is like any other template variable, except that it's available in all templates and macros:

```
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
 $twig->addGlobal('text', new Text());
```

You can then use the text variable anywhere in a template:1

```
 {{ text.lipsum(40) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also add the whole array to Twig:

```
$theme_name = 'layout1';
$somevar = 'blah';

$theme = array(
    'name' => $theme_name,
    'something' => $somevar
);

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$app["twig"]->addGlobal("theme", $theme);
```

In your template, you may then output named elements of this array:

```
{{ theme.name }}
{{ theme.something }}
```

HTH